# Docker - installing flask fails

Tags: python, docker

I am running docker-ce on Ubuntu 16.04. While building my custom app it fails as it is not able to install Flask, which is required for the Python app.

I am behind my organisation's proxy, so I have used inline proxy as well. But still it fails.

Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt \ 
        --proxy https://10.70.52.146:3128 \
        --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask
Redis
```

Output:

```
Step 7/10 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt     --proxy https://10.70.52.146:3128   --trusted-host pypi.python.org<br/>
 ---> Running in 3d92822e4d79<br/>
Collecting Flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)'),)': /packages/7f/e7/08578774ed4536d3242b14dacb4696386634607af824ea997202cd0edb4b/Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl<br/>
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:<br/>HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/7f/e7/08578774ed4536d3242b14dacb4696386634607af824ea997202cd0edb4b/Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)'),))

The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt     --proxy http://10.70.52.146:3128    --trusted-host pypi.python.org' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What does this error refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables as build parameters should solve your problem.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Build command:

```
docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=https://10.70.52.146:3128 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=https://10.70.52.146:3128 .
```

Setting your proxy address outside of your Dockerfile is also a better practice, because it would allow you to reuse this Dockerfile from outside your organization's network.

Comment: You saved my day. I had been trying this for past 2 days, but I still wonder why it doesn't work when PROXY args defined inside Dockerfile.